# Can't run a templated yaml Azure Devops pipeline with dynamically created stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**My problem**

I try to create templated yaml Azure Devops pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: envs
  type: object
  default:
    -  QUAL
    -  PROD
    -  PREPROD
    
stages:
- template: Orchestrator.yml
  parameters:
   name: envs
   type: object
   default:
      -  QUAL
      -  PROD
      -  PREPROD
```

This is my template:

```
parameters:
 envs: {}

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.envs }}:
  - stage: ${{ env }}
    jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      steps:
        - script: echo Deploy project
          displayName: 'Deploy'
    - job: Tests
      steps:
       - script: echo Unit tests
         displayName: Test 1
```

But I get this error message:

> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. The array
> must contain at least one element. Parameter name: stages

OK, I modify my main script like this:

```
parameters:
- name: envs
  type: object
  default:
    -  QUAL
    -  PROD
    -  PREPROD
    
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
       - script: echo Compilation completed...
         displayName: 'Compile'

- template: Orchestrator.yml
  parameters:
   name: envs
   type: object
   default:
      -  QUAL
      -  PROD
      -  PREPROD
```

This time pipeline runs, but only first Job. The Template is not loaded.

**What I need**

I was able to make this scenario working with a single file script, but I would like to make it working with a templated script.

Is this scenario supported? How I can do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have a sample as reference:

1. In the template YAML file (here I name it `template.yaml`), write as this.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: envs
  type: object
  default:
  - QUAL
  - PROD
  - PREPROD

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.envs }}:
  - stage: ${{ env }}
    displayName: 'Stage ${{ env }}'
    jobs:
    - job: job1
      displayName: 'Job 1'
      steps:
      - bash: echo "Current job is job1 in ${{ env }}"
    
    - job: job2
      displayName: 'Job 2'
      steps:
      - bash: echo "Current job is job2 in ${{ env }}"
```

2. In the pipeline YAML (here I name it `pipeline.yaml`), write as this.

```yaml
trigger:
- main

extends:
  template: template.yaml
```

3. **Result**
   [image]

If you do not want to hardcode the value of the parameter '`envs`' in `template.yaml`, you can write like as below.

1. In `template.yaml` write as this.

```yaml
parameters:
- name: envs
  type: object
  default: []

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.envs }}:
  - stage: ${{ env }}
    displayName: 'Stage ${{ env }}'
    jobs:
    - job: job1
      displayName: 'Job 1'
      steps:
      - bash: echo "Current job is job1 in ${{ env }}"
    
    - job: job2
      displayName: 'Job 2'
      steps:
      - bash: echo "Current job is job2 in ${{ env }}"
```

2. In `pipeline.yaml` write as this.

```yaml
trigger:
- main

stages:
- template: template.yaml
  parameters:
    envs:
    - QUAL
    - PROD
    - PREPROD
```

3. **Result**. Same as above.

To view more details, you can see "[YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#template-references)".

Comment: thank you. Where do you find the doc for extends? I found samples in the doc, but without any explanation

Comment: Hi @FrédéricDeLèneMirouze, you see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template